# Could add file to internal stage in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-stage

The below is my code

```
put file://C:\Users\Smart\AppData\Local\Temp\Weather\demo.txt @SAB_INTERNAL_STAGE_2 auto_compress=false;
```

I couldnot add my file to the internal stage . I use the code in the worksheet of web UI.

Please suggest a workaround.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use SnowSQL to upload the file:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql.html

Or you can use the classic web interface to load data:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-web-ui.html

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation, "The command cannot be executed from the Worksheets Worksheet tab page in either Snowflake web interface; instead, use the SnowSQL client to upload data files, or check the documentation for a specific Snowflake client to verify support for this command"

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/put.html#usage-notes